# Spock test: Eclipse doesn't seem to recoganize the data variables in Where clause

Tags: eclipse, groovy, spock

I have a Spock test that uses `where` clause. In Eclipse the test file was opened with Groovy Editor, but the data variables both in the code ("testName") and in the `where` clause (testNum and testName) are underlined. The maven build works fine.

Can someone let me know how to fix this issue in Eclipse?

```
  @Unroll
  def 'Test #testNum'() {
      def tname = testName

      ......

      where:
         testNum  |  testName
          '1'     | 'test #1'
  }
```

Comment: You can't... IntelliJ recognises them, but Eclipse doesn't

Comment: @tim_yates  Thank you.  I hope Eclipse would have a plugin for it.

Answer (score 1):

I did not use Eclipse for quite some time, but maybe defining test parameters could be less confusing for Eclipse:

```
@Unroll
def 'Test #testNum'(String testNum, String testName) {

    def tname = testName

    ......

    where:
    testNum  |  testName
    '1'      | 'test #1'
}
```

Comment: Spock transform dynamically updates AST to "def 'Test #testNum'(Object testNum, Object testName) {", so I would recommend @Michael 's suggestion to get type completions for String.

Answer (score 0):

I can get rid of the underlines by running the Spock transform add this to the end of eclipse.ini:

```
-Dgreclipse.globalTransformsInReconcile=org.spockframework.compiler.SpockTransform
```

However, the inferred type of testName is Object (see my comment under the other answer).

[image: Eclipse Groovy editor with Spock test]